# Declaring parts of page as multi-language friendly

Tags: search-engines, images, language, text

The main parts of my site are multiple-language friendly since every user naturally selects pictures and thumbnails they want to see. The text (which to most guests is very unimportant) is english. The navigation on my site is relatively simple as well to guests who don't understand english since I use arrows for previous and next.

My question is, is there a way that I can declare portions of my page as 100% multi-language friendly (especially the images and image navigation)?

Here's what I was thinking in HTML code but I don't think its correct:

```
<p>English text</p>
    <span lang="multi">
        <a href="page2.htm">
            <img src="arrornextpage.jpg" width=100 height=100>
            <p>Next page</p>
        </a>
    </span>
<p>More English text</p>
```

If I can't declare portions as multi-language friendly in HTML, is there a way to do it in webmaster tools of any search engine?

And the reason I want to do this is so that foreign-language search engines can understand that people don't really need to understand english to use my site to find a picture, and then I want to get ranked high in foreign-language search engines like baidu.com

Comment: If your site is that easy to localize, you should create copies of your site in every language with the small amount of translated text.

Comment: True but the amount of text is at least 200 words per page so that crawlers can see that I have "content" on my site. trying to convert that to make foreign search engines happy will be a royal pain because then I'd have to do keyword optimization in foreign languages that I don't know. I suppose I need to go to school to learn all languages of the world?

Comment: Translation services are sometimes affordable, depending on how much text you have and how much search engine traffic you are getting.  It sounds like you have little enough text that it could work for you.   I also ask users to do translations.   I've built tools that allow users to translate some of my websites.    Just putting up a "volunteer to translate this site" will often get a response from one of your multilingual users.     For the international sites, you can also just start with titles and add more text later.

Comment: Users that can’t perceive the image would still need to understand English.